# SearchBar - Hiding on Tap accidently in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, search, hide, searchbar

I have **Search Bar** in **Navigation Bar**..

*Screenshot:*

[image]

and when I tap on textfield, its hide and its not searching..

*Screenshot:*

[image]

I'm out of ideas how to fix this.

**Source code: http://pastebin.com/z5XWwmN6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```